# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when using ZXing library in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, zxing, undefined-symbol

### What I am trying to do

Integrate [Zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), QR code reader framework, in my iPhone project. I checked out ZXing sdk from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout). I ran the sample project coming with ZXing, named ScanTest, without any issues. But when I try to integrate the library with my project I am getting the error mentioned.

### Project specification

- **Target OS** : iOS 6.0
- **Deployment target** : iOS 5.0 or above.
- **Tested on** : iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS.
- **Xcode** : Xcode 4.5.1
- **ZXing version** : 2.0

### Problem

When I build, after doing every integration step in [ZXing readme file](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README), I am getting build errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::Detector::computeDimension(zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, float) in libZXingWidget.a(Detector-B8B28E953F840D47.o)

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      zxing::Exception::Exception(char const*) in libZXingWidget.a(Exception.o)
      zxing::common::StringUtils::guessEncoding(unsigned char*, int, std::map<unsigned int, std::string, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::string> > >
```

There are 27 errors like that.. I only copied the first two.

### What did I found out

Well, I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930156/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-scnetworkreachabilitycreatewithaddre) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559256/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649378/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-what-does-this-error-mean), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027627/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-adding-cocoaasyncsocket), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619941/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-after-importing-rncryptor),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235993/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architectu) threads in stackoverflow, all with the same error message. None of the solutions worked for me.

Then I found [this closed thread](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1364&can=1&q=iOS%206&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary) in ZXing forums discussing the same issue. From that discussion, some possible solutions are (worked for some)

> *The first error is (probably) because you haven't renamed main.m to main.mm. The second error is (probably) because you're not linking
>   against the widget library*

I also renamed my main.m, cross checked whether I have added the library only to find I surely had. So this is not the case.

> *After I changed the
>   Architectures of the library to "Standard (armv7, armv7s)" to match my
>   main project I was able to successfully compile the app.*

My project, target, library project (for debug, distribution, release) architecture is given as **`Standard (armv7, armv7s)`**. So no luck there either.

Then they closed the issue saying this,

> *The zxing projects have been updated to add the armv7s arch and remove the armv6 arch. These changes are required (1) to build for the
>   iPhone 5 which is armv7s and (2) to build at all since Xcode 4.5 does
>   not include support for armv6. If you have your own project files,
>   you'll need to make these changes yourself. These are general changes
>   not specific to zxing so if you have trouble, you make get
>   more/quicker help in a general forum like StackOverflow.*

So here I am, in StackOverflow.

### One more point

In ZXing integration [README file](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README) , the first step in integration is,

> *1) Locate the "ZXingWidget.xcodeproj" file under "`zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/`". Drag ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and drop it
>   onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files"  sidebar.  A
>   dialog will appear -- make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and
>   "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project" before clicking "Add".
>   Alternatively you can right-click on you project navigator and select
>   'Add files to "MyProject"'.*

When I dragged the ZXingWidget.xcodeproj file to my project, there was no dialog. The project directly added to the project and I could not set, "copy items" and "Reference Type" properties. I don't know if it is a new feature of Xcode 4.5 or a bug. That is the only step I couldn't correctly follow as per the README file.

Well, you have all the information that I have with me. I have been trying to fix this for 6 hours. Any idea?

Comment: Hi I integrated the project with help of your comments.But still i am facing errors after integration successfully.I run the scan test(type of code in our project) example also but i tried to barcode examples.I imported few files from BarcodeExample.I got Duplicate Interface definition of a class "ResultParser".How can i resolve this?

Comment: for me it was adding libc++.dylib to my project.

see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070556/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-opencv-xcode

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well, at last I got it working.. For anyone who encounters this in the future..

1. Rename the main.m file to main.mm.

   ZXing's README states why we need this

   > *It can happen that when trying to build your own project with ZXingWidgetController you get linker errors like "undefined reference
   >   to". If this error looks like a c++ undefined reference, then renaming
   >   main.m into main.mm (Objective-C++ source suffix) may fix the problem*
2. Rename the file (ViewController/View) which uses ZXing libray
   functions so that it also has .mm extension.
3. Check **architecture** settings across project. Give
   **architecture** and **valid architecture** as **armv7 armv7s** in your project settings, target settings, and ZXing project (which you
   added to your main project) and target settings.
4. In main **project** -> **Build Settings** scroll and find out the
   options, **C++ Language Dialect** and **C++ Standard Library**.
   Select options **"Compiler Default"** for both of them. (This is the
   step I missed, It is needed because newest XCode template has
   compiler default settings different to what they were in older
   versions).
5. You also might have to set ZXingWidget's "**Build Valid Architecture
   Only**" flag set as `NO`. In my case, this field was already `NO`

These fixed the issue for me..

### Update


On December 2013, [Google has retired ZXing iOS/Objective](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/L2oGZllqwXI) C port. So Zxing project for iOS is no longer maintained and updated for new iOS versions. Also Zxing doesn't have support for Arm64 architecture which is one of the standard architecture as per new XCode versions.

So developers are encouraged to move over to the [native Apple framework to read barcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) which is available from iOS7 onwards. See [this](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/) for a step by step tutorial.

Comment: The first three are necessary. (1) and (2) are covered in the README.  (3) is the key for moving to Xcode 4.5 from an earlier version and those changes have been made to the projects in SVN but older projects will need to be upgraded. (4) is the default in the zxing project files so if you had to change them it's (presumably) because you had already customized them.

Comment: @smparkes Regarding (4), nope, I hadn't customized them .I created a new project using xcode (empty project)template using xcode 4.5.1 and it has compiler settings different.

Comment: Ah, yes. I can replicate that. Ugh. I guess we should test zxing against the new defaults. Double ugh.

Comment: @smparkes Yes, I thought it is better to mention it in the README file rather than making developers waste their time over it.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to post a patch or the suggested wording to the mailing list or create an issue, that'd be great. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: @smparkes opened an issue.. See [issue 1415](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1415)

Comment: This only half worked for me.  I am also compiling OpenCV in the same project, and this switch removes some errors about ZXing but adds some about OpenCV in a very similar manner to the first errors.  Anyone have some help here????

Comment: (4) is the magic fix for when you've added ZXing to your newly-created XCode 4.5.2 project via cocoapods.

Comment: Step 4 was the magic fix for me, thank you for answering this!

Comment: Please also add jumbob answer to yours. For me it worked adding both answers to my project ;)

Comment: I tried a lot and was not able to fix the compile time errors raised after importing the ZXing Library. @Krishnabhadra you really saved lots of my time. +1 for you.

Answer (score 10):

I've followed all of the suggestions above, and while everything compiles fine, the linking fails:

```
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
  zxing::qrcode::Detector::computeDimension(zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, float) in libZXingWidget.a(Detector-B8B28E953F840D47.o)
  zxing::GridSampler::checkAndNudgePoints(zxing::Ref<zxing::BitMatrix>, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) in libZXingWidget.a(GridSampler.o)
  zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::decodeNumericSegment(zxing::Ref<zxing::BitSource>, std::string&, int) in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
  zxing::qrcode::Mode::forBits(int) in libZXingWidget.a(Mode.o)
```

...
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:

```
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(QRCodeReader-F470BE6889D3F76D.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(Decoder-3DF771F40A970F8E.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(FormatReader.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(QRCodeReader-C190599C861BFE46.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(DecodeHints.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(BinaryBitmap.o)
  ___cxx_global_var_init in libZXingWidget.a(DecoderResult.o)
```

and so on...

I'm running Xcode 4.5.2. I've renamed main.m to main.mm, my view controller was also renamed from .m to .mm, architecture everywhere is "armv7 armv7s".

Sigh...

*Update*

Someone on the Apple devforums had the answer to my problem:

> It looks like you have mismatched C++ standard libraries. Your project's build settings are using clang's C++ standard library, but libZXingWidget.a was compiled to use the GNU C++ standard library.
>
> Try this: open ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and set the "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++", then Clean everything and rebuild.
>
> If that doesn't work, try setting "C++ Standard Library" to "libstdc++" in both your project and ZXingWidget.xcodeproj

The first suggestion did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by changing one value on the project you dragged and dropped in to xcode.

[image]

Set:

Build Active Architecture Only -> Debug -> No

Hope that helps people :)!

Answer (score 6):

This solved the problem for me. Nothing else worked.

[image]

Comment: This solution helps me launch Cocos2d-x v2.2.2 C++ project. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It may also be necessary to set the ZXingWidget target's "Build Active Architecture Only" flag to "NO".

Answer (score 1):

I've followed all of the suggestions above, and while everything compiles fine, but still fail, the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController initCapture] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
"_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:-[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so, you add CoreVideo.framework, the compile will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I went over everything multiple times and after countless tried it turns out I just needed to Clean my project. This was necessary after changing the C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library to Compiler Default. Something simple I do all the time but I missed it and wasted 30 minutes.