# OpenCV ZXing incompatibility on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, xcode4.5, zxing

I'm trying to work with ZXing and OpenCV in the same project.  You wouldn't think this would be this rare of thing to do, but I guess it is.  I am having some serious compatibility issues between the two.  I can only get one imported without the other.

I start with OpenCV and everything works fine.  Program runs as expected.  Then I add ZXing, and I get about 27 compiler errors.  There is a stackoverflow question that address this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968369/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-using-zxing-library-in-xcode-4-5).  So I change my C++ compiler settings to match what this question suggests, and it fixes the ZXing problems, but then opens up a whole new set of errors.  These errors are related to OpenCV now(see below).

EDIT:
It seems that depending on the C++ compiler, its a one-or-the-other type deal.  In fact, if you change the c++ standard library from libc++ to libstdc++ you will get one to work and not the other.  No way I can see to get both at the same time
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question.  This applies best to anyone using zxing and opencv in the same project.

1. Go to the project settings -> Target -> search for c++
   a.  Switch c++ Language Dialect to Compiler Default
   b.  Switch C++ Standard Library to libc++
2. Go to the ZXingWidget.xcodeproj -> ZXingWidget -> search for C++
   a.  Switch c++ Language Dialect to Compiler Default
   b.  Switch C++ Standard Library to libc++
3. There will be a compiler error saying that ZXing can't compile to libc++ because it's currently set to support iOS 4.3.  Go into ZXing widget again, and change the deployment target to be 5.0 (sorry all of you trying to still support < 5)

This fixed my problem. Basically what was happening is that zxing and open cv were compiling on different versions of c++, which was causing some strange issues

Edit: For reference, I was using ZXing 2.1 and OpenCV 2.4.3 (Newest versions at the time of the question)

Comment: Thanks! I was going around in circles for ages trying to get OpenCV and ZXing to compile at the same time, and this worked.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else!  Seems to be just a strange issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I use your solution but a little different. At step2,I change both to Complier Default, because if I use your suggestion,the error still there.So I checked the setting in ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and found that it set both Complier Default, so I changed my project setting the same as ZXingWidget.xcodeproj.
But thanks to your hint and helped me a lot!

Comment: At the time I did it, my solution worked without any errors.  I think both of these libraries have been updated though, so that might be true