# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 erros in project using zxing GreyscaleLuminanceSource XCode 5

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, zxing

The error in my iOS 7 project, with a Deployment Target = 6.1, that uses the latest ZXingWidget:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "zxing::GreyscaleLuminanceSource::GreyscaleLuminanceSource(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
  -[SSAColorCardReader readImage] in SSAColorCardReader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The device connected to my Mac is iPhone 5S.

The project is setup as follows:  In Target's Build Settings Architecture = Standard, Build Active Architecture Only = NO, and Valid Architectures = armv7.

A post that closely relates to my question and have tried the recommendations with no success is [here (SO post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968369/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-using-zxing-library-in-xcode-4-5).  Reviewing this one and others like it and trying out their suggestions I still can't get past this one issue. **update*** Do you know what I might be doing wrong? ***  The ScanTest app works when I compile it for iPhone 5S, so I'm hopeful a solution can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:On deployment target iOS7 there seems to be the need to set the compilers to C++ 11 (sdt) as well as libc++ (LLVM)

After switching those settings the build runs successfully