# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when using ZXing library in XCode 5.1

Tags: ios7, zxing, armv7, i386

i need to scan QR Code for that i have used Zxing 3rd party library but i got following error :

> "undefined symbol for architecture armv7"in libZxingWidget.a
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:

```
  zxing::qrcode::Detector::computeDimension(zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, zxing::Ref<zxing::ResultPoint>, float) in libZXingWidget.a(Detector-B8B28E953F840D47.o)

  zxing::GridSampler::checkAndNudgePoints(zxing::Ref<zxing::BitMatrix>, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) in libZXingWidget.a(GridSampler.o)

  zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::string&, std::string const&, char const*) in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
```

i have done all setting which is explained in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968369/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-using-zxing-library-in-xcode-4-5) .

Project Descriptions :

```
IOS-SDK : 7.1
X-code  :  5.1 
Mac OS " 10.9
Zxing version : 2.0
```

Please Reply me as soon as possible , 
your help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same version of the C++ runtime library as the ZXing library?

Comment: where to check this about C++ runtime library

Comment: I guess you'll need to check the Makefile/Xcode project settings for the library and ensure they match your project's settings.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer , as i am new in IOS Dev

Comment: OK tell me what C++ runtime library your app uses?

Comment: i have set com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0 under build setting->build Option->compiler for C/C++/objectiveC
and also set under Build Setting->Apple LLVM Compiler 5.1 -> C++ standard Library and C++ Language Dialect and set Default Compiler for this

Comment: Is the library `libstdc++` or `libc++`?

Comment: Nevermind I cannot even see which version of the source code you are using.  This is too complicated so I am out.

Comment: if you remove the `armv7` from architectures, **temporarily** you will solve the problem, but in long term you need to find other well-suported 3rd party solution, because the actual compiler defines the supported architectures, and if your 3rd party solution does not support any of those, you will be in a serious trouble with your project in future.

Comment: Droppy Thanks for your reply i have solved this by changing the C++ library to libstdc++ , thank you